# Is it possible to build an asynchronous Python code for handling socket requests using raw async and await?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on a project to learn more about async and await in Python.

My idea is to build a "webserver" which can handle multiple concurrent requests using asynchronous Python.

In order to learn more about how "raw" async code (using `async` and `await`), I am trying to build this without resorting to using a library like `asyncio`.

This may not be possible. What I have found so far is that it doesn't seem to be possible to do this without resorting to using `select` to check if a socket has data which can be read using `socket.recv()`.

In which case, using `async` to create asynchronous functions is pointless, since `select` can be used directly to check if a socket has waiting data. This provides concurrency without the need for `async` functions.

This is what I tried first:

```
async def handle_connection(connection:socket.socket):

    while True:

        request = connection.recv(4096)

        if len(request) < 1:
            print(f'socket closed')
            break
        else:
            decoded_request = request.decode()
            print(f'{decoded_request}')

            response = '+PONG\r\n'
            encoded_response = response.encode()
            connection.send(encoded_response)


def main():

    with socket.socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:

        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        server_socket.bind(('localhost', 6379))
        server_socket.listen()

        while True:
            connection, address = server_socket.accept()
            print(f'accepted connection from {address}')

            handle_connection_coroutine = \
                handle_connection(connection=connection)

            # Start coroutine execution
            try:
                handle_connection_coroutine.send(None)
            except StopIteration as stop_iteration:
                print('stop iteration')
                print(stop_iteration.value)
```

This doesn't quite work because the code execution blocks when it gets to `connection.recv()`. Rather than blocking here it should really yield execution back to the calling function, which can continue to call `accept()`. Of course, `accept()` itself would also have to change to be non blocking and yield control back to any other code which might be waiting.

My second idea was to turn this into an asynchronous generator function by using `yield`. The statement `yield` should be executed if the `connection` object has no waiting data.

There seem to be two ways to do this:

- use `select`
- set the `connection` object to non-blocking and catch an exception

The first option, using `select` seems pointless. It would make more sense to maintain a list of `connection` objects in the `main()` function, and call `select` from within `main()` instead to dispatch regular (non-`async`) functions to handle the incoming request.

I'm not sure about the second option. Catching an exception (which is the most likely thing to happen if no data is waiting) seems inefficient, clunky.

I had one final idea which is really just a guess.

- perhaps `asyncio` has some low level async version of a socket which one can call `await` on?

Instinctively I wanted to build this using `async`/`await`. Network sockets behave asynchronously so it would make sense to model the problem using an asynchronous method.

However I am not sure exactly how to do it. I don't want to use the event loop concepts available from `asyncio` directly, because this is a learning problem.